# How to upgrade android market to Google play

Tags: google-play-store, 2.1-eclair

I am using Micromax Android A60( version android 2.1 ) phone since two years ago.
Now the Market app is not working. When I download any other app it gives error download unsuccessful. Even the Facebook app which is already downloaded to the phone is also not working.

Is this problem because of Market is not upgraded to Google Play?

Why is my mobile is not upgrading Market to Google play? How can I upgrade it?

On Google I got following steps to upgrade Market App but not able to do 3rd step.

Follow these steps to upgrade it manually on your Android device:

1. Go in to Settings in your Android device and then Apps.
2. Look for Market under the "All" tab and then press clear data.
3. Now open the newly updated Play Music app (Google Music). `(This step not found)`
4. Hit that little Market icon in the bottom tray.
5. Confirm Google Play upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

[Google Play requires Android 2.2 or higher](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/190860?hl=en).  Since your phone  has 2.1, it won't run.  You'll either need to upgrade Android (which may not be possible with your phone) or sideload any apps you want to install from now on.

Comment: Google play is working on my phone. I have done restore factory settings and its working :) Thanks a lot for your response

Comment: That's good, and interesting - are you sure your phone is running 2.1, then?

Answer (score 0):

You can download from [Softpedia](http://handheld.softpedia.com/get/Business/Shopping/Android-Market-121182.shtml). Before that, however, you will need to make sure you have selected the `Unknown Sources` for installing applications.